# c# read text file find min max average

Tags: c#

I am studying at TAFE but the class and myself are getting no help from my lecturer at all.

I need to read from a txt file and find the min max and average from it and print it to the console.

The previous exercise was to get min max average from an array and I have written this and it works fine. I am using VS2012.

I have written the code to read the text file and print it to the console - but i cannot find the min max and average. I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when i run the program.

Note that I have used the same code to find min max average as from an array... I feel this might be the issue but I cannot work it out!!

Here is my code for the array...

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] hoursArray = { 1, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 8, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8 };
            for (int i = 0; i < hoursArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(hoursArray[i].ToString());
            }

            {

                {
                    int low = hoursArray[0];
                    for (int index = 1; index > hoursArray.Length; index++)
                    {
                        if (hoursArray[index] < low)
                        {
                            low = hoursArray[index];
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Lowest Hours Parked = " + low);

                int high = hoursArray[0];
                for (int index = 1; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
                {
                    if (hoursArray[index] > high)
                    {
                        high = hoursArray[index];
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Highest Hours Parked = " + high);

                    int total = 0;
                    double average = 0;
                    for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
                    {
                        total = total + hoursArray[index];
                    }

                    average = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;
                    Console.WriteLine("Average Hours Parked =" + average.ToString("N"));

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned this works fine. Now for my problem...
I have written the code to display the data from the text file as per below with my comments...

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader hours = new StreamReader("hours.txt");
        string number = "";

        while (number != null)
        {
            number = hours.ReadLine();
            if (number != null)
                Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        //list of numbers above is all ok when running program

        int total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < number.Length; index++)
        {
            total = total + number[index];
        }
        average = (double)total / number.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average.ToString("N2"));

        int high = number[0];

        for (int index = 0; index < number.Length; index++)
        {
            if (number[index] > high)
            {
                high = number[index];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Highest number = " + high);

        int low = number[0];

        for (int index = 0; index > number.Length; index++)
        {
            if (number[index] < low)
            {
                low = number[index];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Lowest number = " + low);
        hours.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem in your second chunk of code is you read in the numbers but dont store them anywhere, so no, you cant use them later. You read them all in to number (assuming that no one wrote cat in the middle of your file) but, you dont then place it into an array or list. Take this as a hint and see if this aids you

Comment: You are storing only the first number in a string variable and you are looping through the characters of that string to calculate the total, high and low. Instead, create a List<int> and read all lines not just the first line (the condition in while should change), cast the string to integer for each line, and store the integer number in the list(or an array).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using *Linq*:

```
// First of all define the source - it can be an array, file - whatever:
// var source = hoursArray; // e.g. source for the array
var source = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")         //TODO: put actual file here
  .SelectMany(line => line.Split(',')) //TODO: put actual separator here
  .Select(item => int.Parse(item));

// having got source (IEnumerable<int>) let's compute min, max, average

int max = 0;
int min = 0;
double sum = 0.0; // to prevent integer division: 7/2 = 3 when 7.0 / 2 = 3.5
int count = 0;
boolean firstItem = true;

foreach (item in source) {
  sum += item; 
  count += 1;

  if (firstItem) {
    firstItem = false;
    max = item;
    min = item;
  } 
  else if (item > max)
    max = item;
  else if (item < min)
    min = item;
}

// Finally, formatted output
Console.Write("Min = {0}; Max = {1}; Average = {2}", min, max, sum / count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.ReadLines` to read the file contents and then convert those to `int` array using simple `Linq` statements.

```
int[] hoursArray = File
  .ReadLines("filepath")  // Read all lines,
  .SelectMany(s => s.Split(",").Select(int.Parse)) // Split by ',' and convert them to int.
  .ToArray();
```

Once you do this, rest of the code should work as it is.

Also one more suggestion, there are predefined methods/functions on array to get [`Average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340304.aspx), [`Min`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370460.aspx) and [`Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370588.aspx).

You could just do.

```
var avg = hoursArray.Average();
var min = hoursArray.Min();
var max = hoursArray.Max();
```

Comment: `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines` usually a better choice

Comment: That's true, for large files it is always advised to use `File.ReadLines` will update. Thanks @DmitryBychenko

Comment: Although the code is shorter, the solution provided by @Dmitry Bychenko is faster as there's only one loop needed.

Comment: I don't get your point, Dmitry solution also uses linq and is more or less same, what do you mean by single loop?

Comment: To make the calculations for minimum, maximum and average I mean.

Comment: Ohh ok...got it, instead of using min,max separately one could do with single loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("filePath");
        int[] hoursArray = (text.Split(' ').ToArray()).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
        int max = hoursArray.Max();
        int min = hoursArray.Min();
        double avg = hoursArray.Average();
```

Comment: Although the LinQ code is shorter, the solution provided by @Dmitry Bychenko is faster as there's only one loop needed.